# What is the difference between creating a camera class and GLU.gluLookAt function in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I wonder about the difference between creating a camera class and GLU.gluLookAt function in OpenGL ES.Some people asks how can we create a camere class in OpenGL ES but i can't understand why they asking.There is a function gluLookAt and we can use this function for camera issues.What is the advantage of creating a camera class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have to store the variables to pass on to gluLookAt.

Either you wrap them into a camera class, or you store them outside of a camera class...

Comment: So if we move the camera we have to use gluLookAt.Some people mention about using translate and rotate functions for representing the camera.What can we say about that?

Comment: Well, you can do that aswell, but wether you use gluLookAt or matrix multiplication is not related to where you store your actual variables.

Comment: Okey but what about the performance?Which way is more suitable?gluLookAt or translating,rotating?

Comment: @droidman It shouldn't make much difference. Keep in mind that any matrix function (like `glTranslate/glRotate`) runs on the CPU anyway. And since `gluLookAt` isn't even an OpenGL function but a small utility function it also runs on CPU and does nothing more than assemble a matrix and call `glMultMatrix`. Or it may even call some combination of `glTranslate/glRotate`. Considering the less driver calls and 4x4 matrix multiplications, assembling a matrix yourself and then calling `glMultMatrix` may be a bit faster, but who knows if your `gluLookAt` does that (though it is very likely).

Comment: Also i want to look my surface with some angle.How can i perform this in OpenGL ES?